# Django Rest Framework sending Request to External API - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an API for my application to send a POST request to an external API. So for example, if my app hits endpoint `/myapp/api` I want it to call out to an external API and grab some data. In this case, I need this to be a POST request because in order to get the data that I want, I need to pass in some values.

I have made this POST call directly to the external API via Postman successfully many times, and I'm now trying to reproduce that in my python code.

In my **views.py**, I have this:

```
class MyAPPViews(APIView):
    def post(self,request):

        crt = 'path/to/crtfile'
        key = 'path/to/keyfile'
        
        #here I tried to reproduce the headers from the postman call 
        #as best as I could just to be extra specific
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': '/*/',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,br',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        }

        payload = {
            "unitList": [
                "CFQU319303"
            ]
        }
        res = requests.post('external/api/url', headers=headers, data=payload, cert=(crt,key))
        print('this is the true http resonse: ',res.status_code)
        data = res.json()
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": data})
```

in my **urls.py** I have this

```
path('externalAPI',MyAPPViews.as_view()),
```

Now, when I try to go into postman and hit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/externalAPI`
I get a 500 status code returned and the JSONDecodeError of Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). I understand that this means that basically the json response was empty and there was nothing for it to parse.

Is there anything blatantly wrong with my views.py code?

**EDIT** Within the `res = requests.post('external/api/url', headers=headers, data=payload, cert=(crt,key))`, I had to change `data=payload` to `data=json.dumps(payload)`. I'm assuming it didn't like the way I formatted my payload initially. After that, I also deleted everything but the `Content-Type: application/json` out my `headers`  dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, it's just a wrong URL in your call of the external API, as you are using some path without a domain.
So instead of

```
res = requests.post('external/api/url', headers=headers, data=payload, cert=(crt,key))
```

it should be sth. like

```
res = requests.post('https://SOMEDOMAIN.ORG/external/api/url', headers=headers, data=payload, cert=(crt,key))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am using the full url like 'https://domain/blah/blah'

Comment: What does the request return?
Which status code? And did you have a look at the raw body (res.content)? What is it?

Comment: It returns a HTTP 500 code. The res.content output is this: b'unitList=CFQU319303'

Comment: Figured it out, had to wrap my payload in json.dumps() within the request.post line. Appreciate the help troubleshooting!

Answer (score 0):

Within the `res = requests.post('external/api/url', headers=headers, data=payload, cert=(crt,key))`, I had to change `data=payload` to `data=json.dumps(payload)`. I'm assuming it didn't like the way I formatted my payload initially. After that, I also deleted everything but the `Content-Type: application/json` out my `headers`  dictionary.